# Add target attribute to asp:MenuItemBinding in MVC project

Tags: html, asp.net

I have been asked to have one menu item open in a new tab. The menu items are populated from an XML file that is created from an SQL database query. So, I have managed to add the attribute to the XML for the needed URL in the code behind.

But I get an error when I try and bind it:

> Could not bind to the 'target' property (specified by TargetField) while databinding Menu. Please check the Bindings fields.

```
<DataBindings>
<asp:MenuItemBinding TextField="Title" ToolTipField="Tip" NavigateUrlField="Url" TargetField="target"/>
</DataBindings>
```

A few typical menu items...

```
<MenuItem Title="Accounting" Tip="" Url="xxxx.aspx?pstr_group=Accounting&amp;pstr_image=accounting.gif">
      <MenuItem Title="Invoices" Tip="Recall Invoice" Url="xxxx.aspx" target="_blank" />
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Title="Outlook Web Access" Tip="Outlook Web Access" Url="https://xxxx" target="_blank" />
```

The Outlook Web Access menu item is what they want to open in a new tab.

Comment: Post the XML file and the code that you used to add the attribute. by the way, since you're creating the XML file from the database, why don't you add a `target` column to your database?

Comment: @Racil I was thinking that as well. I think I will ask the lead if that is ok. As it feels like the best way to do it. I know why the bind failed: it is because I missed a few items in the xml when I added the target in the code behind.

Comment: OK, then the question should be closed since you solved the issue. Yes, adding it to the database has the advantage of controlling it from the database in the future without having to change the code.

Comment: @Racil if I don't add the column to the database then I need a hardcoded if statement in the code behind which is the dumb part... what if the name or url of the menu item changes in the database. my code would stop working.... thanks for the hep

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "controlling it from the database in the future without having to change the code". :), but also you can change the target for any other link, all from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I know why the bind failed: it is because I missed a few items in the xml when I added the target in the code behind.